# javascript eval statement JS Frames error

Tags: javascript

In this legacy application there is a javascript eval statement:

```
 eval(getElementText(VALUE[0]));
```

The command that it generates is a call to another function.
However, in the screen that I'm dealing with that function never gets called in Firefox.  Instead FireBug generates this information:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
>   [nsIDOMWindowInternal.alert]"
>   nsresult: "0x80040111
>   (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location:
>   "JS frame ::
>   http://localhost/mywebserver/default.asp?bn=0.12345E-02&p=1&p2=1
>   :: ParseABCScreen :: line 718" data:
>   no]

In IE9 believe it or not I get a little further but then I get a very generic unspecified error.  Which shows me nothing.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is returned by `getElementText(VALUE[0])`?  Some quick googling seems to be saying it is related to AJAX.  Is AJAX involved? (the legacy part makes me think it isn't).

Comment: getElementText(VALUE[0]) returns a function which the eval runs...  And yes AJAX is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've managed to patch together from some searching is that this error occurs when you have an ajax call and in the error callback you attempt to check the status of the XMLHttpRequest.  Apparently you're not supposed to do that.

Apparently it only happens in firefox because they're the only ones that follow the spec exactly.

Comment: Note that this also implies that your ajax request is failing and this error message is just hiding that fact as the callback is blowing up.

Comment: interesting...  I'm trying to find where it is failing because as of right now I'm expecting 2 steps to complete but it fails right after the 1st one....  I'll keep hunting.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally comes when trying to `eval` a javascript code with large amount of `escaped data`.
System considers it as an attempt to `inject` some `mallicious data`.

One workaround is to put a `try/catch` statement on `eval`.